# wpa_supplicant connection issue: iw dev wlan1 link shows connection, but network unreachable

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, wpa-supplicant

I've been testing a Wifi card in my machine and I can't seem to get it to connect to my home router. The card is a `ralink rt37`, I compiled the modules that I needed into the kernel and downloaded a firmware file, I can now see the card using `ifconfig -a`. I can also bring the card up using `ip link wlan1 up`. Then when the device is up, if I run `iw dev wlan1 scan` I can see the SSID of my home router.

Now it seems the card is functional I want to connect to my router. The router is secured with WPA, so I need to use `wpa_supplicant` (as far as I understand). I tried following [this tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=263136) to get set up.

I have followed their steps and have the following files:

- `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

  ```
  ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
  ap_scan=1

  network={
    key_mgmt=NONE
  }

  network={
  ssid="SKY183C6"
  scan_ssid=1
  proto=WPA RSN
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  pairwise=CCMP TKIP
  group=CCMP TKIP
  psk=719d0a2d74b09536ce21cecda0851142a2e83d2a56b406098b22012ea0f536f9
  }
  ```
- `/etc/network/interfaces`:

  ```
  # Configure Loopback
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static 
  address 192.168.0.20
  netmask 255.255.255.0

  auto wlan1
  iface wlan1 inet static
  address 192.168.0.90
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 0.0.0.0
  pre-up wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan1 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
  post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
  ```

I can then run the command `wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan1 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf &` and then run `ip dev wlan1 link` and I see the following output:

```
    Connected to 4c:17:eb:a1:83:c7 (on wlan1)
SSID: SKY183C6
freq: 2462
RX: 295890 bytes (1942 packets)
TX: 53549 bytes (1379 packets)
signal: -82 dBm
tx bitrate: 36.0 MBit/s
```

It seems that I'm past the authentication stage but I don't have a connection, there's no IP assigned to wlan1, and when I try `ping 8.8.8.8` I get a message saying `network unreachable`.

If I run `route` I see this:

```
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

My suspicion is that I've not set the interface file up properly, in particular the `gateway` line. If anyone can give me any help I'd be really grateful. Sorry for the long post, just wanted to give as much of the relevant info as possible

Comment: Why aren't using using NetworkManager?

Comment: This is in an embedded environment with an OS I have compiled myself.

Comment: You can use NetworkManager still in a headless environment, it provides a command line tools, `nm-cli` and `nm-tool` for headless systems.